# The ForeignKeyAttribute on property is not valid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I've read [How Should I Declare Foreign Key Relationships Using Code First Entity Framework (4.1) in MVC3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5542864/how-should-i-declare-foreign-key-relationships-using-code-first-entity-framework) but I can't get my call to yield any results.  It has the following error:

> The ForeignKeyAttribute on property 'Footer_Item_Header_ID' on type
>   'MyBlog.Tbl_Footer_Item' is not valid. The navigation property
>   'Tbl_Footer_Header' was not found on the dependent type
>   'MyBlog.Tbl_Footer_Item'. The Name value should be a valid navigation
>   property name.

On this line:

```
Dim footerNavElements = db.Tbl_Footer_Headers.Where(Function(i) i.Footer_Header_Order = 1).Single.Items
```

Here is my parent model:

```
Imports System.Data.Entity
Imports System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations

Public Class Tbl_Footer_Header

    <Key()> Public Property Footer_Header_ID() As Integer
    Public Property Footer_Header_Content() As String
    Public Property Footer_Header_Order() As Integer

    Public Overridable Property Items As ICollection(Of Tbl_Footer_Item)

End Class

Public Class FooterHeaderDbContext
    Inherits DbContext

    Public Property Tbl_Footer_Headers As DbSet(Of Tbl_Footer_Header)

End Class
```

Here is my child model:

```
Imports System.Data.Entity
Imports System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations

Public Class Tbl_Footer_Item

    <Key()> Public Property Footer_Item_ID() As Integer
    <ForeignKey("Tbl_Footer_Header")>
    Public Property Footer_Item_Header_ID() As Integer
    Public Property Footer_Item_Content() As String
    Public Property Footer_Item_Link() As String
    Public Property Footer_Header_Order() As Integer

    Public Overridable Property Header As Tbl_Footer_Header

End Class

Public Class FooterItemDbContext
    Inherits DbContext

    Public Property Tbl_Footer_Items As DbSet(Of Tbl_Footer_Item)
    Public Property Tbl_Footer_Headers As DbSet(Of Tbl_Footer_Header)

End Class
```

What can I do to make the action yield a result without error?  Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your foreign key is annotation should be for the name of the property, not the type.

Your navigation property is Header:

```
Public Overridable Property Header As Tbl_Footer_Header
```

So your annotation, should reference the property.  Change it to:

```
<ForeignKey("Header")>
Public Property Footer_Item_Header_ID() As Integer
```

Comment: Thanks, but I now get an error that says, "`Invalid column name 'Footer_Header_Order'`."  There is clearly a Footer_Header_Order column and property, so what gives?  Thanks.

Comment: I see an integer representing the order: Public Property Footer_Header_Order() As Integer, is that what you intended, or should that be the ID?

Comment: It should be an integer since I will be using it to determine the order of items within the list i.e. 1, 2, 3 (all integers).

Comment: There was a `Public Property Footer_Header_Order() As Integer` line in the child model which shouldn't have been there.  That is the one the error was referring to (not the one in the parent model as I had suspected).  Thanks for your help :)

Comment: not only did this help me understand writing entities from scratch, it also helped me refresh (or at least re-discover) VB.NET.