# How to create relationship between 2 tables in ASP.NET Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework

My main problem is, i want to create relationship between 2 tables.

In SQL Management studio i opened the 2 tables and created a relationship between them.
Then, when i started to Generate a new model from the database in Visual Studio, everything works fine, but i can't see my new relationship.
I've tried to make an association inside the Model.edmx between the two tables, it made a Foreign key inside the 'B' table (that i wanted to reach from 'A'), but after all Visual Studio is crying with an exception: InnerException   "Invalid column name ''
What am i doing wrong?
Where should i see the relationships in Visual Studio Model Browser?
Any other solutions for my problem?

Comment: see this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19591513/how-to-add-foreign-key-relationship-in-entity-framework

Comment: Is the foreign key assigned to the primary key of the other table? Is the column visible in the A table model diagram? The relationship should be shown as a line between the two tables.

Comment: check this : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj206878(v=vs.113).aspx

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways (maybe more and I don't know about it)

1: (Recommended) right click inside your model on an empty space, select `Update Model from Database`, and in last screen click `OK`, since you don't want to add any tables you don't need to select any thing, it will refresh the modeled tables

2: Right click on your table , Add New -> Association, it's like foreign key and select your entities and multiplicity

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but i have already tried these.
The problem with the first option, is when i Update my model from database, it does not refresh the actual relationship that i just added before.
The problem with the second option, is when i create an Association it creates the foreign key for the 'B' model, but after i build my project (and the query executes), it crashes with the exception: "Invalid Column name <The foreign key that the new association created>".