# What's the proper way to delete entities in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I'm having a hard time deleting an object tree. My model doesn't use any kind of built-in cascade deletion mechanism, so I have to perform the explicit deletion of each of the related entities.

The entity I want to delete has 3 levels of indirection (navigation properties)

```
class Parent 
{
    public ICollection<Child> Children { get; set; }
}

class Child 
{
    public ICollection<Grandchild> Grandchildren { get; set; }      
}

public class Grandchild 
{   
}
```

my DbContext is

```
public class Context 
{
    DbSet<Parent> Root {get; set;}
    DbSet<Grandchild> Grandchildren {get; set;}
}
```

Please, notice that the context doesn't expose a DbSet for the class `Children`.

So, what's the correct way to delete everything under a `Parent`?

Comment: Please show us your current code to delete

Answer (score 0):

First you need to make sure, Entity Framework [has a Foreign Key](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19591513/2441442).

Then you should be able to [cascade delete](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/cascade-delete-in-code-first.aspx):

> Cascade delete automatically deletes dependent records or sets null to
>   ForeignKey columns when the parent record is deleted in the database.
>
> Cascade delete is enabled by default in Entity Framework for all types
>   of relationships such as one-to-one, one-to-many and many-to-many.

So the following code should remove every children

```
var parent = _dbContext.Single(predicate)
_dbContext.Remove(parent);
_dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I think it's doesn't work for me. The Context I use is generated using a DB-First approach and I don't have control over it. Every related entity generates a navigation property and a foreign key. I'm getting errors like this:
 SqlException: The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_XXX_XXX". The conflict occurred in database "XXXX_XXXX", table "ABC", column 'ID_XXXX'.
The statement has been terminated.

Answer (score -1):

I guess it will be enough to remove DbSet<> declarations you dont need and then migrate the database. 
PowerShell:

```
dotnet ef migrations add [name]
dotnet ef database update
```

Edit: **above applies if you used code-first approach.**