# Foreign Key in Code First Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

My question is this. Let's say I have a Category class and Product class. And they are implemented like this : 
Category :

```
public class Category
    {
        public Category()
        {
            this.Products = new ObservableCollection<Product>();
        }

        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public virtual ObservableCollection<Product> Products { get; private set; }
}
```

And Product :

```
public  class Product
    {
        public int ProductId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
        public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
    }
```

My question is this. If their id names were both "Id", how could I set the same relationship between Category and Product? In this example I can easily put CategoryId in product because the IDs have different names. What if they had the same name? What should I do? Thanks.

Comment: You haven't, but how can I achieve the same relationship? Is there anything extra to do? Both Category and Product is inherited from the same base class. And the class has "Id".

Comment: Have you had a look at the http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/jj591620.aspx article. Search for 'Configuring a Many-to-Many Relationship'. You need to use the modelBuilder to map the relationship.

Comment: You don't need them to have the same name. If you want the name in the database tables to be identical, you can do that by using the `[Column(Name="ID")]` attribute to decorate your `ProductId` and `CategoryId` fields in their respective class definitions.

Comment: @AlexBarac They have to be ID in class definitions also.

Comment: @jason Is there a particular reason for that constraint?

Comment: @AlexBarac it's a requirement that I can't change.

Comment: I would prefer to refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5542864/how-should-i-declare-foreign-key-relationships-using-code-first-entity-framework. I hope this would give you an idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think just renaming their Id(s) to "Id" work perfectly as you expected.

```
public class Category
{
    public Category()
    {
        this.Products = new ObservableCollection<Product>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ObservableCollection<Product> Products { get; private set; }
}
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
}
```

## Result

[image: Result from database]

Comment: So you mean there is nothing additional thing to do to set the relationship?

Comment: you need to understand the [convention](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj679962.aspx), but if you want different name as navigation property you can use [ForeignKey attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.foreignkeyattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [FluentApi](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591617.aspx)

Comment: the convention fits your requirement, so yes, there is nothing to set up

Comment: How does it know thaat? Categories_CategoryId is same as the Id of categories? Thanks.

Comment: It maps the name supplied in the code with the name of the column in the database. If the two names are not identical, then the name of the column is set as an attribute, similar to the one I mentioned in my comment above, for the name of the field in the code.

Comment: the convention bro, "In the Entity Framework, navigation properties provide a way to navigate a relationship between two entity types. Every object can have a navigation property for every relationship in which it participates. Navigation properties allow you to navigate and manage relationships in both directions, returning either a reference object (if the multiplicity is either one or zero-or-one) or a collection (if the multiplicity is many). Code First infers relationships based on the navigation.." - [EF Relationship Convention](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj679962.aspx)

Comment: in this case by adding Category::Products(array) creates the relationship, if you don't have Product::CategoryId, then EF will create Category_Id column in Products table