# Add column in table with ASP.NET identity

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, ado.net, asp.net-identity

I have made a project whit ASP.NET MVC using identity framework. It has created a new table `AspNetUsers`, but I want to add columns into that table like birth day, profile picture etc... How can I do that?

Can I run the query below in my SQL Server Management Studio?

```
ALTER TABLE AspNetUsers ADD ProfilePicture NVARCHAR(100);
ALTER TABLE AspNetUsers ADD BirthDay DATE;
```

Or is it more complex? I can not work with identity framework, so I must do it with ADO.NET and the .NET framework 4.

Comment: You will need to add the appropriate property to your `IdentityUser` class and then create an Entity Framework migration which will then run the appropriate SQL on your database when you execute the migration.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/16/customizing-profile-information-in-asp-net-identity-in-vs-2013-templates.aspx

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I have found it! @James suggested me an article that works.

**Steps:**

1. Type in the console manager this code:

   ```
   Enable-Migrations
   ```

   [image]

   <sup>Source: [blogs.msdn.com](http://blogs.msdn.com/cfs-file.ashx/__key/communityserver-blogs-components-weblogfiles/00-00-00-63-56-metablogapi/0624.image_5F00_thumb_5F00_6736B4A1.png)</sup>
2. In the class `ApplicationUser` add the property you want.

   ```
   public DateTime? Birthdate { get; set; }
   ```
3. in the console manager type this code:

   ```
   Add-Migration "Birthdate"
   ```
4. After it update the database whit this code:

   ```
   Update-Database
   ```

**Result:** a new column is added to the database whit name "Birthdate" and type `datetime` that can be null.

Comment: Thanks for the post.It helped me!In my case I had to add column of type int.I added the column as described on your post but, now I need to define the added int column as foreign key.Do you have any idea how can it be implemented?

Comment: @Michael take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5542864/how-should-i-declare-foreign-key-relationships-using-code-first-entity-framework

Answer (score 11):

**Suppose you want to add a new column named "FirstName":**

**Step 1:** Models/IdentityModels.cs

Add the following code to the "ApplicationUser" class:

```
public string FirstName { get; set; }
```

**Step 2:**  Models/AccountViewModels.cs

Add the following code to the "RegisterViewModel" class:

```
public string FirstName { get; set; }
```

**Step 3:**  Views/Register.cshtml

Add FirstName input textbox to the view:

```
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.FirstName, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
</div>
```

**Step 4 :**

Go to Tools > NuGet Manager > Package Manager Console 
    Step A : Type “Enable-Migrations” and press enter 
    Step B : Type “ Add-Migration "FirstName" ” and press enter 
    Step C : Type “Update-Database” and press enter 
i.e

```
PM> Enable-Migrations
PM> Add-Migration "FirstName"
PM> Update-Database
```

**Step 5:**  Controllers/AccountController.cs

Go to Register Action and add "FirstName = model.FirstName" to the ApplicationUser 
i.e

```
var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email, FirstName = model.FirstName}
```

Comment: Using VS2017 and .Net Core2 no need to use `Enable-Migrations` anymore.

Comment: After adding it, how can i make it being updated or inserted, for example ?